# free ftp, ftps, sftp tool that could process file list

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp, sftp, ftps

Is there is free command line tool for Windows that could take text file (with list of files) and put all that files to remote folder (ftp, stps, sftp).

Currently I'm using separate tool for each of mentioned protocols, and now want a single tool that could work with FTP and FTPS and SFTP.

No cygwin based solutions and no trial versions, please. It is ok, if it is not opensource.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it but [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/introduction) is opensource and  [supports Scripting/Automation](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting)